# Python, как импортировать переменную, изменить её и сохранить в том же месте откуда импортировали

Tags: python

Импортирую переменную из файла, изменяю её. Теперь нужно сохранить её в измененном виде там же откуда взял.
Делал как в учебнике Марка Лутца - 4 издание стр.627. Написано абстрактно и предельно не понятно, я так понял инструкции import и from могут изменить локальные и глобальные переменные, но они не сохраняют изменения внесенные в импортируемую переменную - непосредственно в импортируемом файле. Хотя Лутц пишет, что изменяемый объект используется совместно и вроде как всё должно сохраняться. Кто ни будь просветите, как мне импортировать список, изменить и сохранить его в импортируемом файле.

```
# small.py
x = [0, 1, 2]

from small import x
x[0] = 6
```

Объект изменяемый. При открытии small.py я хотел бы видеть:

```
x = [6, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо открыть файл, в котором хотите что-то изменить, как текстовый, и внести коррективы.
Используйте конструкцию:

```py
with open('filename.py', 'w') as f:
...
```

Comment: Вроде как `with open...`

Comment: @Bogdan спасибо, уже исправил)

Answer (score 4):

Нужно отличать **изменение переменной на этапе выполнения программы** и **изменение исходного кода переменной**.

Автор имеет ввиду изменение переменной в процессе выполнения. А пример в вопросе пытается изменить исходник на диске.

В первом случае автор прав. Но если же все таки нужно менять исходник, то можно поступить, как предложил [@Hyper Elf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1039857/192978).

Хотя, имхо, идея сомнительная писать/редактировать код программы, чтобы редактировать код программы.